# ViewModel in Asp.Net MVC vs Knockout.Js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm really confused about how ViewModel works in the context of KnockOut.js and Asp.Net MVC.

In Asp.Net MVC, ViewModels are similar to DTOs.  They are used to have strongly typed views.  It is considered a good practice, which I've been abinding to as well.

However, recently I got interested in Knockout.js, which uses ViewModels in a whole different way.  I'm still not 100% sure, but ViewModels are like Controllers it seems.

I guess I'm still confused about the ViewModel in knockout.js because its not the same as Asp.Net MVC.  Can you please help clarify these two patterns?

Comment: You are correct. The logic in MVC is inside the controller and a view model in this context is basically a strongly-typed ViewBag or DTO for passing data to the view. In Knockout, a view model is more of the typical MVVM view model that is more like a controller that exposes observable properties for databinding.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC like Angular implements the MVC pattern while KO implements the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @AnthonyChu Thanks for clearing up the confusion.  So, whenever the MVVM pattern is used, the VM is similar to a Controller?  Is this always the case?  Like in windows app development, etc.

Comment: @Anders Yah, Angular JS makes more sense in that context.  KO isn't a full blown framework like Angular JS, but for me it goes perfectly with Asp.Net MVC, enabling rich client experience, and not bringing in too much complexity.  It's just like the missing piece in MVC, that enables dynamic ui.

Comment: @Pathachiever11 Yes, view models on the XAML stack (WPF/Silverlight/WinPhone/Win8) tend to contain logic. In fact that's where MVVM first gained popularity.

Comment: I guess its a matter of taste, I like MVVM better over MVC actually.

Comment: @Anders I like them both because they both enforce separation of concerns.  I'll be doing more MVVM with KnockOut.js, so I'm very excited about that.

Comment: @AnthonyChu Since you answered this question first, can you post your answer as an answer so I can mark it as an answer. not sure if that made much sense...

Comment: Why did I get a -1 vote?  It was a legit question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The logic in MVC is inside the controller and a view model in this context is basically a strongly-typed ViewBag or DTO for passing data to the view for one-way databinding.

In Knockout and anything on the XAML stack, a view model is more of a typical MVVM "view model" that is more like a controller that exposes observable properties for two-way databinding.